# $| (a+b)^n - a^n| \leq n |b|(|a| + |b|)^{n-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, prove that for $n\geq 1$

$$| (a+b)^n - a^n| \leq  n |b|\;(|a| + |b|)^{n-1}$$

I tried using induction

For $n = 1$, $\;| (a+b) - a| = |b| =  1\times |b|\times(|a| + |b|)^{1-1}$

Assume $| (a+b)^n - a^n| \leq  n |b|\;(|a| + |b|)^{n-1}$

$$| (a+b)^{n+1} - a^{n+1}|  = |b| \;| (a+b)^{n} + (a+b)^{n-1}a + \ldots + a^n| $$

But I am unable to figure out how to use the inductive step in this.

Comment: Why do you want to prove it by induction? The  Mean Value theorem is enough.

Comment: But there is no mean value theorem for complex valued functions, no?

Comment: Sorry, it seems  I read the question a bit too fast. However, there is a *Mean Value inequality* for functions of several variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite $\:(a+b)^{n+1}-a^{n+1}$ as
$$\bigl((a+b)^n-a^n\bigr)(a+b)+a^nb$$
and use   the inductive hypothesis and the triangle inequality:
\begin{align}
\bigl|(a+b)^{n+1}-a^{n+1}\bigr|& \le
\bigl|(a+b)^n-a^n\bigr||a+b|+|a^n||b|\\
&\le n|b|\bigl(|a|+|b|\bigr)^{n-1}\bigl(|a|+|b|\bigr)+|a|^n|b|\\
&\le n|b|\bigl(|a|+|b|\bigr)^n+\bigl(|a|+|b|\bigr)^n||b|\\
&=(n+1)|b|\bigl(|a|+|b|\bigr)^n
\end{align}

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: The first step is clever! :)

Comment: @Prags: Thank you, but I think it's rather natural if one wants to proceed  by induction.